# Neater way to write this JSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I have some function that will be called for both these functions of `SomeForm` i.e. onGoClick and onNoGoClicked both have the same function call, is there a way I can tidy this up more? Or is this acceptable?

```
      <SomeForm
        onGoClick={() => {
          cleanupHere(props)
        }}
        onNoGoClicked={() => {
          cleanupHere(props)
        }}
      />
```

Comment: If both are the same function call then use toggle javascript element or give more information

Answer (score 2):

There's not much I can suggest without knowing the context in which you are using this and the implementation of SomeForm. This isn't ideal but since onGoClick and onNoGoClick are executing the same function you could combine them with a predefined function like this:

```
const func = () => {
  cleanupHere(props)
}
// ...
return <SomeForm onGoClick={func} onNoGoClick={func} />
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the way if you have so many props to pass,

```
let someFormProps = {}; 
someFormProps.onGoClick = someFormProps.onNoGoClicked = cleanupHere(props);
<SomeForm {...someFormProps} />
```

Comment: Are you sure assigning those props to `cleanupHere(props)` won't execute the `cleanupHere` function on load rather than on click event?